# How to change nameplate

Tags: halo-reach

I can't find where to change my nameplate ever since *Halo* switched to halo.xbox.com. I have looked in Service Record and Stats, but I cannot find it.

Comment: It looks like it is currently impossible.

Comment: I still don't know but I think you can go into bungie net, sign in then you can change it there or go into service record, if that doesn't work then I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer, you can't do it anymore.

[Here](http://www.bungie.net/News/Blog.aspx) is a question made by a user to an engineer on the user interface team.

> ALI217 Will we still be able to change our nameplates for Halo: Reach?
>
> No. Editor’s Note: Behind that silent veneer rages a storm of evil
>   genius.

NOTES: Maybe not a good link but [Here is a question in they forum](http://halo.xbox.com/Forums/yaf_info.aspx?i=4), I don't have access to this area, maybe you have:

Comment: It doesn't look to me like either of those links go to specific resources.

Comment: the best link is the first that is from an engineer from the dev team

Comment: I mean that the first link goes to the main blog page and the second goes to the forum front page. Neither goes to a specific post.

Comment: What do you mean by  "Behind that silent veneer rages a storm of evil genius" does that mean there is hope?

Comment: Well, was not me who put that note. But if I should **guess** in something about it, then yes =X